# Given an undirect graph $G=(V,E)$, graph $G$ has a vertex cover $B$ of size $k$ if and only if it has a vertex cover $B$ so $|B|\leq k$

Tags: graph-theory

I have a small question about graph theory. In complexity theory I saw the following statement:

> Given an undirect graph $G=(V,E)$, graph $G$ has a vertex cover $B$ of size $k$ if and only if it has a vertex cover $B$ so $|B|\leq k$.

I'm trying to understand why this statement is true. My logic says it is not but I could not disprove it. How to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, we must assume $k \leq |V|$ - if $k > V$, then this proposition is false, since $V$ itself is a vertex cover and $|V| \leq k$, but there is no cover of size $k$.

Clearly, if there is a vertex cover of size $k$, there is some vertex cover $B$ such that $|B| \leq k$.

Now suppose that there is some vertex cover $B$ such that $|B| \leq k$. Then add $k - |B|$ arbitrary nodes to $B$ to get $B'$. Then $|B'| = k$ and $B \subseteq B'$, so $B'$ is a vertex cover of size $k$.

Comment: The arbitrary nodes you added, are not part of $V$?

Comment: @vesii When I say "nodes" I mean "elements of $V$".